# Can someone help me understand instanciating vfp projects?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a vfp project, call it Proj2. It contains some methods that accept paramaters and returns results. Let's say it has a method named addtwonumbers and a method named subtracttwonumbers.

I have another vfp project, call it Proj1. Proj1 instanciates Proj2 by doing loProj2Reference=createobject("proj2")

I need to call Proj2's addtwonumbers method so I do something like x=loProj2Reference.addtwonumbers(1,2)

What is in Proj2 that lets it stay alive so that Proj1 can call it's methods? If in the main prg of Proj2, there is a endless loop, when I instanciate Proj2 from Proj1, it never returns from the line, loProj2Reference=createobject("proj2"). So that does not work. If in the main prg of Proj2 there is a read events, same problem.

So, again, what is in Proj2 that allows it to stay alive so I can call it's methods? I know that if Proj2 is a COM server, this is all doable but if it is NOT a COM server, is this possible?

The answer may very well be that I am way off base and that there is a much better way to look at making use of Proj2's methods from Proj1.

I should also tell you that Proj2 is a VFP project developed using the VFExpress framework. For VFE apps, the application object is the main.prg so I am really instanciating the "Proj2applicationobject" which has no user interface. The reason I am doing this is my VFE framework gives me lots of tools for business objects etc. Proj1 is a regular VFP project. Let' say it has a user interface and needs access to all that data/business object functionality that is in Proj2.

Thanks,
John

Comment: _if Proj2 is a COM server, this is all doable_ -- why not make it a COM server?

Comment: Using "methods of a project" however can be done by instantiating objects based on (custom) classes, e.g. using the `NewObject()` function,like `o = NEWOBJECT("Class77", "Library66", "test55.exe")`

Comment: Stefan, Thanks. "why not make it a COM server?" I have past experience doing that and so I did that and functionally it works. Besides it being a lot more difficult to debug, it seems I am having trouble returning objects from the COM server's methods. It is what I would call squirelly. I have the COM server's method save the return value into a local property (local to the COM server) like oobj1. Then in the calling app immediately after the call to the COM server's method, I do loobj1=ocomserverapp.oobj1....

Comment: ...The calling app's loobj1 is always an object but if you look at it in the debugger sometimes it has no elements and sometimes it only has the first element and sometimes the other elements appear magically a minute later. If I use loobj.element1 it contains null but in the debugger it contains a value. Really squirelly. Anyway, if your reply (the part about newobject is an attempt to show me how to NOT have a COM server, it is going over my head.

Comment: _Anyway, if your reply (the part about newobject) is an attempt to show me how to NOT have a COM server_ -- Yes, the bold line assumes being in the Vfp Command Window, or somewhere in your "Project1" at runtime, and its 1st parameter is the name of the desired class, the 2nd is the name of its library (`VCX` or `PRG` file), the 3rd one is the name of the built "Project2" `EXE`or `DLL`

Comment: ... so that the next line there could look like `result = o.YourMethod()`

Comment: As far as your Question description itself goes, I'm afraid though it sounds to me like a mixture of more than one issues -- and as if we actually would need something like a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example in this case

Comment: Stefan, Setting all that aside for a moment, this will sound unrelated but it would help. When a class is stored in a vcx library, I am guessing it does not have the DEFINE CLASS line. If that same class is stored in a prg, it would start with DEFINE CLASS (I think). How do you take the code from a class library (the vcx) and put it in a prg? Do you just copy and paste the code from the vcx into a prg and add the DEFINE CLASS line to the top of it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, and yes for the `Define Class` line questions, and SO suggests us to post a new Question for an answer to your last Comment :-)

Comment: Stefan, I posted that question about how to turn a class library code into code in a prg. I do not want to answer it myself so that you get credit for answering. John